# xstring functions in section/paragraph headers

Tags: sectioning, strings

In the following example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\foo[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{love}{hate}}

\begin{document}
 \section*{\foo{I love Mondays}}
\end{document}
```

if I remove the `*` from `\section*` the code stops compiling.

1. What is the trick that makes `\section*` work ok with `\StrSubstitute` but not `\section`?
2. Is there a workaround to include the command `\foo` in a `\section` header too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember, section headings are also used for the table of contents, thus expanded and written to the .toc file. Use `\protect` to prevent the early expansion of `\foo`:

```
\section{\protect\foo{I love Mondays}}
```

Alternatively use the optional argument to fix it:

```
\section[]{\foo{I love Mondays}}
```

Have a look at [Fragile and Robust commands](http://texblog.net/help/latex/fragile.html) for explanation.

You can define the command to be robust, avoiding such problems from the beginning:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\foo[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{love}{hate}}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer (and Herbert, too); but I still do not get why the same syntax works with \section*. Moreover, is there a way to modify either \section or \foo so that I can use the second syntax without a \protect or an optional argument?

Comment: @Federico: `\section*` doesn't create a table of contents entry, that's why id doesn't expand `\foo` writing it to the .toc file which causes the problem. You can make it robust by `\DeclareRobustCommand`. I'll edit my answer to add that.

Answer (score 2):

it is a moving argument:

```
  \section{\protect\foo{I love Mondays}}
```